# How to debug early hints loading in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, chromium

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/early-hints.md suggest this is how one would debug if asset was loaded using early hints (103 HTTP status response) like so:

```
performance.getEntriesByName('https://a.test/style.css')[0].initiatorType
// => 'early-hints'
```

https://hg.mozilla.org/try/file/cc6f6c969877f92faf9ebda84653aff9fec62b0b/testing/web-platform/tests/loading/early-hints/resources/preload-initiator-type.html -> would confirm this is true.

Yet when I run this statement in chrome console, i'm getting:

```
performance.getEntriesByName('https://mywebsite.com/img.jpg')[0].initiatorType
'link'
```

Did `early-hints` was replaced with `link`?

Would assume so, but also am seeing no effect on the waterfall chart when early hints get enabled, so chances are chrome is really not respect 103 and does not preload asset. Any other ideas of how to debug early hints in chrome are more than welcome (Using Chrome 106 on OSX).